# Scale and change anchorPoint

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, image, scale

I try to zoom in on the zone where i click an image witch in a UIImageView.
i used CGAffineTransformMakeScale to make scale and i changed imageView.layer.anchorPoint with clicked point coordinates
scale is working, but the image is no more in center, i think i'm wrong on anchorPoint coordinates, i found many articles discussing about it, but it was too complicated

help please !

code:

```
-(void)gestureTapEvent:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    NSLog(@"doubleclic");

    CGPoint touchPoint = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];  
    NSLog(@"Position of touch: %.3f, %.3f", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);    

    float newX = touchPoint.x/imageView.frame.size.width;
    float newY = touchPoint.x/imageView.frame.size.height;


    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5);
    imageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(newY, newX);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The content of the layer draws itself relative to the anchor point. In fact the `anchorPoint` and the `position` of the layer (position roughly corresponds to the `center` of the view) are the exact same point in two different coordinate systems: the anchor point is in the unit coordinate space of the layer and the position is in the superlayers coordinate space. I have a quite detailed explanation about all this [in this article over at the iDeveloper blog](http://ideveloper.co/understanding-the-anchor-point/).

Short solution: set the position of the layer after you have set the anchor point. Setting the frame won't work due to having a transform (see documentation for the frame property for more information).

Another solution (if you are to annoyed by the the position-anchor-point-dance) is to use only a transform. If that case you would concatenate translate, scale & translate to get the final transform. I've written about basically the same thing but for rotations in [this article](http://ronnqvi.st/translate-rotate-translate/). Just substitute rotation with scale :D